# WPF TabControl styled like OSX Tab View

Tags: wpf

How can the WPF TabControl be styled so that it looks like the Tab View in OS-X Cocoa style? I would like the style to show the tab headers with the rounded-corners on both ends, connected headers as buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the folks over at Intersoft have this one nailed, if you want to use their UXTabControl. It's a good prior work if you wanted to use it to style the Microsoft TabControl.

Blog Post : [Mac & Metro-style Tab Controls](http://intersoftpt.wordpress.com/2011/01/05/new-year-goodies-mac-metro-style-tab-controls-updated-samples-and-more/)

Source code : [Mac Styled WPF TabControl](http://www.intersoftpt.com/ClientUI/UXTabControl_Styles.zip)

They turned this
[image: Boring Tabs]

Into this

[image: Mac Styled Tabs]

Comment: thanks for the upvote. A question upvote will help this get found by more people